# If I have two samples of spatial distribution (tweets), how do I test if they're from the same distribution?

Tags: spatial, gaussian-process, kernel-smoothing

If I have two samples of spatial distribution (tweets), how do I test if they're from the same distribution?

What are model is usually used to represent distribution of tweets?

The data I have are scraped from a specific hashtag, containing user id, caption, location, time. It's tourists' data so it's very random, concentrated around tourist attractions. Here's an example

[image]